# AngularJS directive mutate isolate scope data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

## Background

I'm trying to build an AngularJS directive with a 2 way bound isolate scope property. This directive needs to mutate the data to an array in order to be able to display it correctly using `ng-repeat`. I know that an infinite digest cycle will occur when you return a new array from a 'get' function because it's a new array and AngularJS will keep considering the model unstable and keep digesting.

This issue can be solved by not using a 'get' function to return a new array... but this is not an option for me because I need the mutated array to change whenever the source array changes. This is a feature provided by the isolate scope and I would like to not use `$scope.$watch()` because that would require me to inject `$scope` which is what I'm trying to get rid of by using the `bindToController: true` syntax.

## Question

So my question is, considering the background above: What is the correct way of mutating isolate scope data inside an AngularJS directive?

## Code

in Jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/b7ekv4tm/) (notice the infinite digest cycle error when you open the developer tools console)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="IsolateScopeExample" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    <h4>Original data</h4>
    {{vm.dataToMutate}}
    <h4>Mutated data</h4>
    <div mutator data="vm.dataToMutate"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript (AngularJS version: 1.3.14):

```
angular.module('IsolateScopeExample', [])
    .controller('MainController', function(){
        this.dataToMutate = [{a: 1},{a: 2},{a: 3}];
    })
    .directive('mutator', function(){
        return {
            scope: {
                data: '=',
            },
            template: '<span ng-repeat="item in mvm.mutateData()">{{item}}</span>',
            bindToController: true,
            controller: function(){
                this.mutateData = function(){
                    console.log('Mutating');
                    var newData = [];
                    this.data.forEach(function(d){newData.push({b: d.a + 1});});
                    return newData;
                };
            },
            controllerAs: 'mvm'
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why this works, but this is how I normally write Angular with directives. The difference I see is that I use `$scope`. I pass down `dataToMutate` to the directive. In the `link` of the directive, I alter `dataToMutate`. Since it's the same object in the controller, the template updates accordingly. https://jsfiddle.net/b7ekv4tm/2/

**html**

```
<div ng-app="IsolateScopeExample" ng-controller="MainController">
    <h4>Original data</h4>
    {{dataToMutate}}
    <h4>Mutated data</h4>
    <div mutator data="dataToMutate"></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
angular.module('IsolateScopeExample', [])
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dataToMutate = [{
        a: 1
    }, {
        a: 2
    }, {
        a: 3
    }];
}])
    .directive('mutator', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: '=',
        },
        template: '<span ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</span>',
        link: function ($scope) {
            var data = $scope.data.map(function (d) {
                return {
                    b: d.a + 1
                };
            });
            $scope.data = $scope.data.concat(data);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: It is not needed or even unwanted that the directive mutates the original data reference. It just needs to mutate the data for its own scope (by creating a new array for example), but leave the original array as it is.

Comment: @YanikCeulemans Oh, so it's like a computed property thing. You can watch the original array, then create another array in the directive's scope containing the recalculated data. Then have the directive's template listen for it. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/b7ekv4tm/3/ Not entirely sure why you're avoiding watch though.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly like a computed property. The reason i'm trying to avoid using `$scope` is because I'm trying to use the bindToController syntax of AngularJS 1.3+ (which prevents common data de-synchronisation issues with `$scope` parent hierarchies as explained in the article linked by Xeon in the other answer). This new syntax should take care of automatically updating the 2 way bound attributes of the directive onto its controller. Having to use `$scope` to watch all 2 way bound properties is going to become cumbersome when we're dealing with more than just 1 property.

Answer (score 0):

`@Joseph the Dreamer` answer is correct but if you really want to get rid of $scope and use `bindToController` (btw. [great article about this here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html)) you'll have to reuse a reference to the same array.

Actually this is exactly what the docs say. Page where error link points to:

> One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new array every > time it is called. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in getUsers()">{{ user.name }}</div>
```

> Since getUsers() returns a **new array**, Angular determines that the model is different on each $digest cycle, resulting in the error. The solution is to return **the same array object** if the elements have not changed:

```
var users = [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];

$scope.getUsers = function() {
  return users;
};
```

So your soulution would be something like this:

```
controller: function(){
            var mutated = [];
            this.mutateData = function(){
                console.log('Mutating');
                var newData = [];
                this.data.forEach(function(d){newData.push({b: d.a + 1});});
                mutated.length = 0;
                mutated.push.apply(newData, mutated);
                return mutated;
            };
        },
```

Comment: I understand that using the same array object if the elements have not changed will solve my problem. My problem then is to identify when the data **has** changed